# Configuring OpenVSwitch on dumb AP running openwrt

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point, openwrt

I am currently trying to run openvswitch on OpenWrt. Here is the setup I am trying to achieve: I have 2 wireless clients connected to an AP running OpenWRT (my access point is Netgear WNDR3700). The AP is dumb. Then I have the AP connected to a PI. The PI is connected to the Internet, and it is running DHCP. Finally I have onos running on the PI.

Onos can see the devices (the ovs switch) and it can also see the hosts (the two laptops). But the hosts are not assigned any IP addresses. When the wireless interfaces are assigned to the LAN network, they are being assigned IP addresses, but onos fails to see hosts.

============

Here are some updates. I created a wan interface eth1.1, and added it to the ovs bridge. I added a rule in ovs to push any packet incoming at port 2 (wlan0) to port 3 (eth1.1). The PI is connected to the WAN port of the router. I did tcpdump on the ovs bridge, the wlan0 interface, and the eth1.1 interface. I can see arp packets coming from the wireless client on all 3 interfaces... yet when I do TCPdump on eth1 of the pi, I see nothing.

============

Here is the `/etc/config/network`:

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd3c:8eef:8a02::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option type 'bridge'
    option ifname 'eth0.1 eth1 radio0.network1'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option ipaddr '192.168.43.2'
    option gateway '192.168.43.1'
    option dns '192.168.43.1'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'
    option blinkrate '2'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 1 2 3 5t'

config switch_port
    option device 'switch0'
    option port '1'
    option led '6'

config switch_port
    option device 'switch0'
    option port '2'
    option led '9'

config switch_port
    option device 'switch0'
    option port '5'
    option led '2'

config interface 'wlan0'
    option proto 'none'
```

and here is the /etc/config/wireless

```
config wifi-device 'radio0'    
    option type 'mac80211'    
    option channel '11'  
    option hwmode '11g'
    option path 'pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0'
    option htmode 'HT20'

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    #option network 'lan'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'OpenWrt'
    option encryption 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] Here is the change in the /etc/config/network

```
[Solved] here is the change in the /etc/config/network file: 
config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd3c:8eef:8a02::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option type 'bridge'
    option ifname 'eth0.1 eth1 ovsbr'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option ipaddr '192.168.43.2'
    option gateway '192.168.43.1'
    option dns '192.168.43.1'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '1'
    option blinkrate '2'
    option enable_vlan4k '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '1'
    option ports '0 1 2 3 5t'

config switch_port
    option device 'switch0'
    option port '1'
    option led '6'

config switch_port
    option device 'switch0'
    option port '2'
    option led '9'

config switch_port
    option device 'switch0'
    option port '5'
    option led '2'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth1.1'
    #option force_link '1'
    option proto 'none'
    #option ipaddr '192.168.43.4'
    #option netmark '255.255.255.0'


config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '3'
    option vid '3'
    option ports '3 5t'

config interface 'lan1'
    option proto 'static'
    option ifname 'eth0.3'
    #option auto '1'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '2'
    option vid '2'
    option ports '2 5t'

config interface 'lan2'
    option proto 'static'
    option ifname 'eth0.2'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '4'
    option vid '4'
    option ports '1 5t'

config interface 'lan3'
    option proto 'static'
    option ifname 'eth0.4'

config switch_vlan
    option device 'switch0'
    option vlan '5'
    option vid '5'
    option ports '0 5t'

config interface 'lan4'
    option proto 'static'
    option ifname 'eth0.5'

#config interface 'ovsbr'
#   option proto 'static'
#   option ifname 'ovsbr'
#   option ipaddr '192.168.43.3'
#   option netmask '255.255.255.0'
#   option type 'bridge'

config interface 'wlan0'
    option protocol 'none'
```

Note that I added eth1.1,eth0.2,eth0.3, eth0.4, and eth0.5, wlan0 as ports to the ovsbr bridge! :)